# Справка: ошибки перевода

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Не нашел в TransiFex.
Вроде больше во всей справке ничего в глаза не бросилось.

---

**На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?**

Проверьте, на **(не)** задавал ли кто-нибудь ранее ваш вопрос. Можно также задавать вопрос и отвечать на него самому.

---

**Какой тип вопросов лучше не задавать?**

...
Вопросы должны быть достаточно узкими. Если представить, что для ответа на вопрос требуется написать книгу, **(заменить запятую на тире или вставить "то" перед "он")** он явно избыточен.

Если мотивацией спрашивающего является «желание обсуждения...», вопрос не следует задавать. Но если мотивация - «желание, чтобы мне объяснили...», возможно, **(заменить запятую на тире или вставить "что" перед "он") возможно, что я ошибаюсь** это правильный вопрос (разумеется, обсуждения приветствуются в нашем веб-чате в реальном времени).
...
подразумевают ответы, которые объясняют «почему» и «как»;
подразумевают развернутые и подробные ответы;
имеют конструктивный, честный и непредвзятый харатер **(характер)**;
подразумевают обмен опытом, а не мнениями;
требуют подтверждения изложенного фактами и ссылками;
являются большим, чем просто бессмысленное веселое общение.
Более подробная информация содержится в Руководстве по хорошим субъективным вопросам и сообщениях в блогах об ответах на настоящие вопросы.

---

**Что означает статус “закрытый” или “замароженый” вопрос? Почему часть вопросов находится в состоянии “заморожено”?**

Что означает статус “закрытый” или “замароженый” **(замороженный)** вопрос? Почему часть вопросов находится в состоянии “заморожено”?

---

**Почему блокируются вопросы с моей учетной записи?**

Песочнице **(песочница)** форматирования

---

**Почему некоторые вопросы отмечаются как дубликаты?**

Основная задача закрытия дублирующихся вопросов – помочь пользователям найти правильный ответ путем собирания всех ответов в одном месте. Это не означает, что любой дубликат сразу закрывается; нам нравятся (некоторые) дубликаты. **(надо пробел)** Это значит, что один и тот же вопрос можно задать многими способами, и пользователь может не найти ответ, если будет задавать вопрос другими словами.

Comment: «Песочнице» до сих пор не исправлено.

Comment: По «..лучше не задавать» обсуждение открыто: [Редактирование раздела "Какой тип вопросов лучше не задавать?"](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1259)

Comment: Запросил доступ на редактирование статей, когда дадут — исправлю опечатки.

Answer (score 3):

Исправил:

- [Почему блокируются вопросы с моей учетной записи?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) — указанная ошибка и пара запятых.
- [Почему некоторые вопросы отмечаются как дубликаты?](http://%20https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) — указанная ошибка, кавычки, заменил "[Дубликат]" на «[копия]», поправил формулировку.

В отдельных вопросах:

- [Редактирование раздела "Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1259/181472)

Остальное вроде бы уже исправлено.