# Редактирование раздела "Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?"

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, справка, правила

Перевод «[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)» → [«Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?»](http://%20https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

---

#### Заголовок: «Какие вопросы лучше не задавать»

В первую очередь убедитесь, что [вопрос соответствует тематике сайта](/help/on-topic).

Следует задавать исключительно практические вопросы, основанные на реальных проблемах, на которые можно дать однозначно правильный ответ. Абстрактные и дискуссионные вопросы добавляют лишний «шум», споры и отвлекают сообщество от нуждающихся в помощи коллег, не внося ничего полезного.

Вопросы должны быть узкими — если для ответа на вопрос требуется написать книгу, он явно не для этого ресурса.

Если мотивация задающего — «желание обсудить что-либо», то следует воздержаться от публикации такого вопроса; но если мотивация — «желание, чтобы мне объяснили что-либо», то, возможно, это хороший вопрос. *Обсуждения на любые темы, пересекающиеся с тематикой сайта, приветствуются в чате, но не на самом сайте вопросов и ответов*.

**Чтобы вопрос не был отмечен тревогой и, возможно, впоследствии [удалён](/help/deleted-questions), не задавайте субъективные вопросы, в которых:**

- любой ответ правильный, например, «Какой ваш любимый язык программирования?»;
- ответ содержится в вопросе, и ожидается, что другие участники будут добавлять свои варианты, например, «Я использую ... для ... , а что используете вы?»;
- в вопросе нет реальной проблемы, которую можно решить, например, «Интересно, сталкивались ли другие с тем же, что и я?»;
- задается абстрактный, гипотетический вопрос, например, «Что, если произойдет ...?»;
- вопрос является замаскированной демагогией, например, « ... — это плохо, вам так не кажется?».

Приведенные выше примеры адаптированы из [FAQ MetaFilter](http://faq.metafilter.com/tags/chatfilter).

Все же, некоторые субъективные вопросы допустимы, но «некоторые» не подразумевает «любые». Любой, даже субъективный вопрос на сайте должен быть *конструктивным*.

**Конструктивные субъективные вопросы:**

- предполагают ответы, которые объясняют «почему» и «как»;
- предполагают развернутые и подробные ответы;
- имеют конструктивный, честный и непредвзятый характер;
- подразумевают обмен *опытом*, а не *мнениями*;
- требуют подтверждения изложенного фактами и ссылками;
- являются чем-то большим, чем просто бессмысленное весёлое общение.

Более полную информацию можно найти в [«рекомендациям по правильным субъективным вопросам»](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) и публикациях в блоге об [ответах на стоящие вопросы](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/).

Comment: Может быть, просто «Какие вопросы лучше не задавать»?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Вполне! Поправил.

Comment: В остальном я прошёлся по тексту, исправил что мог.

Comment: мета-вопрос: почему текст раздела в вопросе размещён? В общем случае ведь возможны несколько вариантов, как это было с разделом /help/on-topic и поэтому предпочтительно публиковать такие вещи в виде (общего) ответа.

Comment: @jfs Это исправление существующей статьи. Если у кого-либо появляются идеи, как ее улучшить, можно непосредственно вносить изменения в вопрос.

Comment: "дискуссионные вопросы добавляют лишний «шум», споры и отвлекают сообщество от нуждающихся в помощи коллег, не внося ничего полезного" - желаю автору этих заявлений покупать оперативку и новые процессоры каждые 2 месяца, чтобы у него весь софт состоял из копипасты сниппетов, которые совершенно не обсуждались.