# Вопрос, состоящий из нескольких: делить или нет?

Tags: вопросы, обсуждение

Хочу задать несколько вопросов (в чём-то, может, дискуссионных) одной тематики, но не знаю, задать ли их все в одном топике или разбить на несколько.

Плюсы за один топик:

- будет описание подхода, возможно на несколько абзацев, и, скорее всего, куски кода. В случае нескольких топиков придётся дублировать описание или ссылаться на первый
- удобнее оперировать схожими понятиями и терминами

Плюсы за несколько:

- не будет огромной портянки
- скорее всего, отвечать будут на вопросы по-отдельности - можно будет выбрать лучший ответ

Так как быть?

**Дополнение**

В общем, подумал и создал подобный дискуссионный вопрос - [Нагруженные деревья в биоинформатике. Часть 1. Точный поиск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/753397/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-1-%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA). Фактически, только начало дискуссии. Как итог - уже пошли голоса за закрытие.

Comment: "Как итог - уже пошли голоса за закрытие" - неудивительно, там в начале вопроса приписка "Тема создана как дискуссионная", что является типичным магнитом для закрытия (как и надпись "Часть 1" в заголовке). Сформулируйте вопрос(ы) в соответствии с форматом, принятым на сайте, тогда проблемы не будет.

Comment: Вот, в том-то и дело, что на сайте (пока?) нет формата для дискуссий. И очень жаль, т.к. подобный подход очень плодотворен.

Answer (score 7):

Вообще говоря, если это, как Вы выразились, вопросы *дискуссионные*, т.е. предлагается обсуждение каждого вопроса, то тогда лучше задавать несколько отдельных вопросов.

Иначе в ответах/комментариях будут смешаны частичные ответы на отдельные вопросы.

Задавать несколько вопросов в одном имеет смысл, когда есть некоторый *стержневой* вопрос и Вы пишете к нему некоторые вспомогательные, *уточняющие* и *дополняющие*.

Можете посмотреть общие правила написания хорошего вопроса
[здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2487/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0).

Также есть перевод топика с [en.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) - **Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?** - см. [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1259/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C).

Обратите внимание, там говорится, что вопрос должен быть **узким**, т.е. чтобы не надо было в ответ писать целую книгу. Также не приветствуются вопросы типа «обсудить эту проблему»

Comment: Ок. Допустим, дискуссия = чат. Задал вопросы по организации такого чата: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6477/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%83

Answer (score 6):

Отвечая на комментарий:

> Вот, в том-то и дело, что на сайте (пока?) нет формата для дискуссий.
>   И очень жаль, т.к. подобный подход очень плодотворен

На самом деле, на SO не приветствуются не любые вопросы, порождающие дискуссии (это было бы глупо), а только те вопросы, которые в результате дискуссии не создают полезный материал для базы знаний. Формат для дискуссии есть - комментарии, чатики - но предполагается, что после обсуждения должны родится ответы, которые могут повторно использованы многими участниками.

Ваш вопрос, вообще говоря, не является дискуссионным "в плохом смысле". Насколько я вижу, у вас есть конкретная задача (поиск подстроки в строке), описание существующего несовершенного решения (стандартный поиск) и критерий для искомого решения (производительность) - все составляющие нормального вопроса. Проблема в том, что сейчас он оформлен так, что трудно воспринимаем и является магнитом для закрывашек, по нескольким причинам:

- Бессмысленный заголовок. Заголовок должен описывать конкретную задачу/проблему, а не раздел предметной области.
- Бессмысленная приписка в начале вопроса. Начало - важная часть вопроса, т.к. из нее генерируется предпросмотр для результатов поиска, в ней должна быть информация по делу (поэтому приветы и выпиливаются).
- Структурирование текста надписями типа "Вопрос N." Вопрос - не экзаменационный билет, чтобы его делить так. Вопрос вообще должен быть максимально сжатым и не иметь, по возможности, подразделов.
- Неочевиден собственно вопрос (что именно вы ожидаете от отвечающего). Указания на это надо выискивать среди длинного полотна рассуждений, что многим просто лень делать.

Я рекомендую оформлять вопросы как-то так:

1. Описание конкретной задачи.
2. Описание существующих методов решения (попыток решения) этой задачи.
3. Непосредственно вопросы; описание, что именно вы хотите от отвечающих (например "В чем недостаток существующего решения?", "Как усовершенствовать решение, чтобы оно соответствовало такому-то критерию?")

В третьем пункте может быть несколько вопросов, но все по одной задаче. Тогда закрывашки не должны прилетать.

Comment: Не в пику вам, просто для информации: сегодняшнее обсуждение, включая диалоги в чате породили две очень интересные идеи. Банально, но "в споре рождается истина" :)

Answer (score 5):

Не стоит забывать, что у гипотетического автора топика, которого загрызла определенная проблема, могут быть друзья по частичному несчастью :)

Созданный вопрос уже не является собственностью одного человека, он - достяние всего сообщества.

Очень часто то, что требуется автору в одной задаче, состоящей из нескольких вопросов, другим нужно лишь частично. Вот и думаем, что лучше: искать ответ на свой вопрос конкретно или рыться в большом количестве задач, где теоретически можно найти нужное (а зачастую - не найти)?

Comment: Я сторонник вашего мироощущения. Вообще, жаль, если честно, что здесь нельзя создавать топики дискуссионного плана, с поддержкой самой системой.