# Вопросы по организации чата по дискуссионному вопросу

Tags: чат, обсуждение

Вопрос, вытекающий из топика [Вопрос, состоящий из нескольких: делить или нет?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6471/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82).
Если вопрос окажется дискуссионым, стоит попробовать создать чат. Привилегий, чтобы создать новую комнату, мне вроде бы хватает. Почитал английский FAQ. Не всё понял:

1. непосещаемый чат проживет неделю и будет удалён, так?
2. неактивный чат, где поговорили хотя бы 2 человека, будет заморожен. Значит ли это, что всю информацию в любой момент можно будет оттуда вытащить,
   или только последнюю страницу?
3. если я хочу, чтобы чат жил, достаточно раз в неделю продлевать ему жизнь каким-либо сообщением? Или мне просить ещё и коллегу это
   сделать?

Comment: Без правильных тегов комната обречена.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Да. Кроме тех, что достигли требований заморозки, разумеется.
2. Всю. Можете сами просмотреть [список комнат сайта, включающий замороженные комнаты](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&nohide=true&host=ru.stackoverflow.com), найти что-нибудь замороженное и добраться до полного журнала сообщений.
3. Достаточно одного человека. Нельзя, к примеру, заставить бота Feeds, который отправляет в чат новые записи из RSS-лент, держать комнату живой — его сообщения система не учитывает.